# Weird behavior of \theoremstyle

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I just noticed something weird of the `\theoremstyle` command. Here is the code of a sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\begin{document}
\thm 1
\defn 2
\case 3
\thm 4
\end{document}
```

I expected the theorem after "Case" to behave like the first theorem, however the out put looks like this:

[image: Output]

Any explanation or solution? Am I using `amsthm` wrong?

Comment: The correct way to invoke a theorem is `\begin{thm}...\end{thm}`, not `\thm`.  I don't know what specifications there are for using `\thm` as you did.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the same thing. I wish there is some package that automatically make `\thm` as `\begin{thm}#1\end{thm}`.

Comment: Where should it put the `\end{thm}`, if you have no way to show where the theorem ends?

Comment: I think we can close this question, as it's just a small mistake of using environments as commands.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I mean, something automatically provides `\newcommand{\thm}[1]{\begin{thm}#1\end{thm}}` when `thm` is defined as a `newtheorem`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` you are defining a `thm` *environment* that *requires* to be used as

```
\begin{thm}
A statement.
\end{thm}
```

The fact that `\thm` doesn't give errors is just because of the internal implementation of the `\begin` and `\end` commands, which shouldn't really be relied upon.

The `\theoremstyle` declaration uses the property of environments of being a *group* in the TeXnical sense: declarations inside them end their scope at the corresponding `\end` command.

When you do

```
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
```

in the preamble and have `\begin{case}` in your document, LaTeX performs some assignments such as stating that the "Case" label is typeset in italics. This is made by the *internal* `\case` macro (which you shouldn't be using). In this case *no* "end of scope" is seen and so the next instance of `thm` will inherit the font attributes of `case` for the label: being in the default `plain` style, `\thm` doesn't issue font declarations.

The `\begin`–`\end` syntax is also much clearer, in my opinion: it gives visual clues in your input for finding things more easily. It's just a question of training and, maybe, of having a good text editor that inserts the `\begin` and `\end` tags with just a keystroke.